# How to get rid of the Recovery Mode?

Tags: macos, mac

First, I don't understand anything about Macs. My company sends me one, I press a black button on the top right accidentally and now I have a nice padlock icon asking for a password.

After some googling I find out this:

> You might see the lock icon at startup if you try to start your Mac from another volume like an external drive or macOS Recovery.

Ok, nice. So how can I start from the correct volume?

Comment: I suggest you ask the IT department at your company for further instructions. Your company may have configured your Mac to require additional authentication on login, or something has gone awry with this configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you were at the FileVault login screen, where there’s a prompt to press that button if you’re having trouble to be taken to recovery.

As you have a firmware password set, you will need to enter this to continue.

It’s not possible to change the startup disk without entering the firmware password.

Comment: I don't even know what is that ("FileVault login screen"). I just pressed a small black button and it seems like it setup a recovery mode

Answer (score 1):

If you press and hold the startup key for an extended period on newer macs, that puts it in recovery mode. From there you would hold the startup until the mac powers off.

Then connect to power and open the lid and if needed, press briefly the power button and let go. The system will boot from any available startup disk without needing to press any keys.

Here are startup keys if you need to navigate things further. Without knowing your macOS version, model / processor type, how the company set up the Mac - we may not have all the information to help you avoid calling them for direct support.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255

Comment: After open the lid, I see the padlock screen

Comment: You may be stuck if the system doesn’t see a viable boot volume and you’re [now firmware locked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/437952/5472). This isn’t about removing recovery and just you got this machine into a locked state or it was locked remotely before or after you got it @anvd

Comment: Remote support can't do nothing. I will just ask for a windows or linux pc. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Booting into Recovery mode normally does not display a padlock, nor does it ask for a password.

Apple's [Support pages](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204455) show this image for when a Firmware password has been set. This prevents anyone without the password from 'tinkering' with the Mac, outside of normal running.

[image]

If you don't know the password, you need to contact your company's IT department.

You may still be able to restart the Mac and trigger normal boot-up. Hold the black button down for 5 seconds, until the Mac goes 'dead', and then restart.